# How to disbale UITextview text selection

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Disable `UITextview` selection disable or disable copy/paste menu but I want not disable my links in `UITextview` 
I try but both are disable any solution ?

Comment: Show the code that you used

Comment: [textview setSelectable:No];

Comment: that code disable my web links in uitextview not press able

Comment: post your code then we can know what is issue

Comment: i implement all anwser but copy /paste menu still showing

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/82mgtip0bb2xt2h/Untitled.png i want this

Comment: any solution i already check all answers

Answer (score 2):

if you simply want to disable copy/ paste. you should use a Subclass for your UITextView

then simply do this to disable all items from the menu:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}
```

if you only want to disable copy and paste, you can do:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:) || action == @selector(copy:))
        return NO;
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in – textViewDidChangeSelection: delegate method,

```
textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0,0);
```

Comment: i use this textView.selectedRange = NSRangeMake(0,0);
but copy /paste menu and selection working

Answer (score 1):

Implement the following as per your requirement. it will work for sure:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
  if (action == @selector(selectAll:))
   return NO;

  if (action == @selector(select:))
   return NO;

  if (action == @selector(cut:))
   return NO;

  if (action == @selector(copy:))
      return NO;

  if (action == @selector(paste:))
   return NO;

 return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can over ride `UITextField` for `- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender` . See below code -

```
@interface MYLoginTextField : UITextField

@end

@implementation MYLoginTextField

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:) || action == @selector(copy:) || action == @selector(cut:) || action == @selector(select:) || action == @selector(selectAll:) || action == @selector(select:))
        return NO;

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}

@end
```

Comment: that code not working

Comment: How exactly did you try this? I have updated the complete code taken from my working project.

Comment: i use this code in subclass that can't press links in textview and not showing copy/paste menu. - (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder { return NO; } then i write this code then allow to press links but in other text show "Define" - (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender { if (action == @selector(selectAll:) && action == @selector(select:) && action == @selector(cut:) && action == @selector(copy:) && action == @selector(paste:)) return NO; return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender]; } plz help me in this case.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
yourTextView.editable = NO
```